# create batch file to move and rename files if exsist

Tags: batch-file

creating a batch file

source: `deploy_pkg\conf\*`

destination: `E:\conf\*`

First scenario:

I want to move multiple files (ex. `web-config.xml`) if `web-config.xml` already exists in destination rename to `web-config.xml.bak`, then move new `web-config.xml` to destination.

2nd scenario:

If no files exist in source `deploy_pkg\conf\*` then leave destination file as is.

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
update.bat c:\from c:\to
```

contents

```
set FROM=%1
set TO=%2

for %%F in (*.*) do (
 rem echo FILE == %%F
 if exist %TO%\%%F ren %TO%\%%F %TO%\%%F.bak
 copy %FROM%\%%F %TO%\%%F
)
```

it is roughly